# Meaning of やら in this sentence

Tags: meaning

I'm not sure how to interpret やら in this line:

> そしてランディ・オートン、ジョン・シナと、同じ時代を戦ってきた人間としてやらなきゃいけないなと思ってますけど

From this paragraph:

> 「真っ先にＡＪというのもありますし。お互い新しい成長もあるだろうし。そしてランディ・オートン、ジョン・シナと、同じ時代を戦ってきた人間としてやらなきゃいけないなと思ってますけど」と将来的な対戦に目を輝かせた。

I'm not even sure about the meaning of this line, but I think it's saying that the speaker wants to fight ランディ・オートン and ジョン・シナ or wants to fight at his level.
In the context the speaker is being interviewed about his debut in the WWE (he is from japan and I think he's talking about his new opponents. Also all this guys have similar age, maybe that has something to do with 同じ時代)

Comment: Uh, it's not just やら, it's やらなきゃ, a contraction of やらなければ. You're familiar with ～てやる, I presume?

Comment: @Nothing at all  so, is it と + して(verb) + てやる??

Comment: Yes, it is indeed.

Comment: @Nothingatall Actually it isn't ～てやる but として (postposition) + やる (verb).